# Nifi: High Availbility (HA)

Tags: high-availability, apache-nifi

Reading from the link below, i believe when a node goes down in the Nifi cluster, the data will not be processed until the node goes back up  --- so flow files/data handled by the failed node will not be taken over by another node in the cluster.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/High+Availability+Processing

The link above is relatively old ( almost 2 years ago) , just wondering if Nifi HA story is still the same or not.  If it is still the same,  does anyone know if nifi has any plans to fix it in the future ?

thanks,

Comment: Hi @mary-jane, 
did you solve the problem? 
do you have some insights to share with the community?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely something the community is still interested in, but it hasn't been worked on yet (as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: wow, this is a major issue. I am surprised that there is still no plan to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka or queue engine can help you to solve this problem on architecture level

Answer (score 0):

If a node goes down and the flowfiles are stored on the local filesystem, then it is impossible to get those to offload to another node.

However, by configuring your nodes to store the flowfiles on a HA storage system, when a node dies, you should be able to replace the node and it should pick up from where the failed system left off.